# Why do my photos have major flare on red clothing?

Tags: lens-flare, color-red

I have been shooting outdoors in heavy sun, people wearing red, and I am far away. I am getting so much flare on the red. I am using a lens hood. An other suggestions?

Comment: Can you link to any example images?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are red objects coming out unnaturally in my photographs?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11232/why-are-red-objects-coming-out-unnaturally-in-my-photographs)

Comment: In fact, all four questions so far under [tag:color-red] are about this same phenomenon. :)

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you are experiencing overexposure in red color channel. You can check this from a histogram that displays color channels separately - the red channel has a peak at the right end. Many cameras base their exposure metering on green channel, because human vision is most sensitive to green.

Unfortunately, possibility of restoring information in an overexposed color channel during post-processing is limited (if you shot RAW) or none (if you only have JPEGs).

Next time in similar situation, you could try shooting with reduced saturation setting and/or underexpose (i.e. use negative exposure compensation).

Comment: On my camera, this is highly influenced by the tone curve option selected for in-camera JPGs. "Bright" gets its punchier look at the expense of pushing bright colors over the edge. I've learned to prefer "Natural" and usually work with the Saturation slider down a notch or two.