# How to get colors right with Nikon D300?

Tags: color-management, white-balance, color-violet

With my Nikon D300 I have been photographing dahlias. I have been unable to get accurate colors of some of the flowers particularly in the magenta-violet range. I have adjusted white balance manually as well as tried adjusting it in Auto with fine tuning on the G M axis. I am shooting in Raw. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried a UV filter?  Perhaps the Nikon is reacting to excessive UV.

Answer (score 2):

I have a D300 and have exactly the same problems.  I utilize a combination of the Picture Control System and then post editing using Nikon's NX2 RAW editing software to adjust contrast and saturation until I can see the detail which the colour depth is losing.

Also check out my answer to the following as it is very pertinent to this question .. [Why do bright red flowers end up without details?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10735/why-do-bright-red-flowers-end-up-without-details/10751#10751)